# Hebrew words affecting order in cat statement in R

Tags: printing, hebrew

I am trying to print a Hebrew word and then a number in R from left to right, but the cat print statement is printing word and count right to left.  Reversing the order in the cat statement does not resolve this. How I can I correct this?

Comment: Try using the `paste()` function.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work.  Can you provide an example of this working for you?